# Fading in/out view in ScrollView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to fade in and out a `TextView` while scrolling a `ScrollView` vertically. Whenever I scroll slowly, I'm getting it right making the `TextView` invisible as it faded out. The problem is, when I scroll faster, it is not completely gone. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

    if (t > oldt) {
        float newAlpha = alpha - 0.02f;
        if (newAlpha >= 0.0f) {
            for (View view : fadingViews) {
                view.setAlpha(newAlpha);
                alpha = newAlpha;
            }
        }
    } else {
        float newAlpha = alpha + 0.02f;
        if (newAlpha <= 1.0f) {
            for (View view : fadingViews) {
                view.setAlpha(newAlpha);
                alpha = newAlpha;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: onScrollChanged is called many times during a quick scroll. you probably don't need to run the alpha change that many times

Comment: `<ScrollView android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">` Did you try anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a fading edge in your `ScrollView`, you might consider adding some like the following in your layout xml of `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">
```

However, I am thinking you are looking for something like the following to set alpha in your views programatically.

```
mScrollView.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged () {
            // the scrollposition that the fade will start
            int mScrollThreshold = 100;
            // how fast the view will fade with the scroll -- use multiples of 10
            int mScrollVariance = 40;
            int scrollY = mScrollView.getScrollY();
            // if the difference between the scrollthreshold is +/-mScrollVariance, show the view accordingly
            float newAlpha = 0;
            float scrollDisparity = scrollY - mScrollThreshold + (view.getHeight() / 2);
            // scroll is up past the variance, so start to show it
            if (scrollDisparity > 0 && scrollDisparity < mScrollVariance) {
                newAlpha = scrollDisparity / mScrollVariance;
                view.setAlpha(newAlpha);
                // scroll is below the variance so start to hide it
            } else if (scrollDisparity >= -mScrollVariance && scrollDisparity < 0) {
                newAlpha = scrollDisparity / mScrollVariance;
                view.setAlpha(newAlpha);
                // just in case the user swipes too fast, these are the fallbacks
            } else if (scrollDisparity > mScrollVariance) {
                view.setAlpha(1);
            } else if (scrollDisparity < -mScrollVariance) {
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    });
```